# Find the student with the highest GPA

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SjuStudent {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> Xnumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    Xnumber.add("X03024327");
    Xnumber.add("X03124586");
    Xnumber.add("X03324556");
    Xnumber.add("X03424496");
    Xnumber.add("X03524696");


    ArrayList<Integer> age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    age.add(21);
    age.add(19);
    age.add(18);
    age.add(22);
    age.add(25);



    ArrayList<String> fname = new ArrayList<String>();
    fname.add("Wei");
    fname.add("Frank");
    fname.add("Dave");
    fname.add("John");
    fname.add("Joe");


    ArrayList<String> lname = new ArrayList<String>();
    lname.add("Guo");
    lname.add("Dave");
    lname.add("Ming");
    lname.add("Chow");
    lname.add("Lin");


    ArrayList<Double> GPA = new ArrayList<Double>();
    GPA.add(3.60);
    GPA.add(3.78);
    GPA.add(3.20);
    GPA.add(2.60);
    GPA.add(1.60);


    for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println("X number: " + Xnumber.get(i) + "\n" + "age: " + age.get(i)+"\n"+"First name: " + fname.get(i)+"\n"+"Last name: " + lname.get(i) +"\n"+"GPA: " + GPA.get(i));
    System.out.println();

    }
    Double min = GPA.get(0);
    Double max = GPA.get(0);
    for(int a=0; a<GPA.size();a++) {
        double number = GPA.get(a);
        if(number < min) min=number;
        if(number > max) max=number;

    }
    System.out.println("min = " + min );
    System.out.println("max = " + max);
}
}
```

So I am making an arraylist of a list of 5 students grades. Was wondering how I can print out the student with the lowest GPA and the student with the highest GPA along with the student info. Look something along these lines.

```
/*
 X number: X03524696
 age: 25
 First name: Joe
 Last name: Lin
 GPA: 1.6
*/
```

Currently, at the moment, I was only able to print out, only the lowest GPA and highest GPA.

Comment: It's right there in `fname` and `lname`. What's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use hashmap or treemap?

Comment: wrap all the data for a student in an object; put them in a list, sort this list by GPA and then takte the first and last and print them

Comment: you can put student object into list then then using custom sorting you can get the data by GPA then using geeters you can get firstname and lastname

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way to solve the problem, but given the code and not changing it drastically to meet the problem description you can simply store the index of the min and max GPA when finding them, and use this index to access each ArrayList.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

ArrayList<String> Xnumber = new ArrayList<String>();
Xnumber.add("X03024327");
Xnumber.add("X03124586");
Xnumber.add("X03324556");
Xnumber.add("X03424496");
Xnumber.add("X03524696");


ArrayList<Integer> age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
age.add(21);
age.add(19);
age.add(18);
age.add(22);
age.add(25);



ArrayList<String> fname = new ArrayList<String>();
fname.add("Wei");
fname.add("Frank");
fname.add("Dave");
fname.add("John");
fname.add("Joe");


ArrayList<String> lname = new ArrayList<String>();
lname.add("Guo");
lname.add("Dave");
lname.add("Ming");
lname.add("Chow");
lname.add("Lin");


ArrayList<Double> GPA = new ArrayList<Double>();
GPA.add(3.60);
GPA.add(3.78);
GPA.add(3.20);
GPA.add(2.60);
GPA.add(1.60);


for(int i=1; i<5; i++) {
System.out.println("X number: " + Xnumber.get(i) + "\n" + "age: " + age.get(i)+"\n"+"First name: " + fname.get(i)+"\n"+"Last name: " + lname.get(i) +"\n"+"GPA: " + GPA.get(i));
System.out.println();

}

int minIndex = 0;
int maxIndex = 0;
for(int a=0; a<GPA.size();a++) {
    double number = GPA.get(a);
    if(number < min){
      minIndex = a;
    }
    if(number > max){
     maxIndex = a;
    }

}
System.out.println("min = " + min );
System.out.println("max = " + max);

//Get information using minIndex
fname.get(minIndex);
lname.get(minIndex);
age.get(minIndex);
gpa.get(minIndex);

//Repeat with max index
fname.get(maxIndex);
lname.get(maxIndex);
age.get(maxIndex);
gpa.get(maxIndex);
}
```